# centering a list within a 100% div

Tags: html, css

Im working on responsive code just now and for some reason i cant get 2 lists to display in the center of the div that's 100% width for mobile view.  Is there something that im missing out in the css code below that might be causing this to not to display centered?

both lists have classes of .social-media and .top-nav

*** *HTML* **********

```
 <div id="gezzamondo">

 <div class="header">

 <img class="logo" src="images/gezzamondo-logo.jpg" alt="Web designer Glasgow | Gezzamondo" title="Web designer Glasgow | Gezzamondo"  />

 <ul class="top-nav">
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="social-media">
 <li><img src="images/twitter-social.jpg" alt="Gezzamondo on Twitter" title-"Gezzamondo on Twitter"/></li>
 <li><img src="images/behance-social.jpg" alt="Gezzamondo on Behance" title="Gezzamondo on Behance"/></li>
 <li class="last"><img src="images/dribbble-social.jpg" alt="Gezzamondo on Dribbble" title="Gezzamondo on Dribbble"/></li>
 </ul>


 </div><!-- close header -->
 </div><!-- close gezzamondo -->
```

** *CSS* ****

```
 body {
background-color:#C09;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
 }

 img{
max-width:100%:
 }

 #gezzamondo{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
 }

 .header{
background-color:#FFF;
height:215px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
 }

 #gezzamondo .logo{
width:183px;
height:83px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:20px;
 }

 #gezzamondo .top-nav{
list-style: none;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:300;
margin:0 auto;

 }

 #gezzamondo ul.top-nav li{
float:left;
margin-right:30px;
 }

 #gezzamondo ul.top-nav li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#333333;
 }

 #gezzamondo .social-media{
position: absolute;
list-style: none;
width:162px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#06F;
 }

 #gezzamondo .social-media li img{
height:44px;
width:44px;
 }

 #gezzamondo .social-media li{
float:left;
margin-right:15px;
 }

 #gezzamondo .social-media li.last{
float:left;
margin-right:0px;
 }

 #gezzamondo ul.top-nav li a:hover{
border-bottom:7px #FF0099 solid;
color:#333333;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the position to absolute in #gezzamondo .social-media, just remove the position and it should center.

Comment: see with the .top-nav, do i need to give that a width before it will center?  its difficult to determine its width as its text floated left with margin right on each to space them out... whats the best way to remove the margin from the last one in the list and determin the ul width

Comment: are you trying to center .top-nav too, if so make the following change #gezzamondo ul.top-nav li{
display:inline;
margin-right:30px;
 } remove the float left

Answer (score 0):

I've used the code you supplied, it looks a mess to in jsfiddle (example code is not complete etc). I think this should do it for you, or at least get you [closer](http://jsfiddle.net/aWmss/3/). What I did was basically wrap the social ul in two divs. center-social spans the full width and center-s trys to provide an idea of a  width so the uls can be centered. Try it out on your actual page and it should display correctly. It's only applied on the social ul in the example.

```
<div id="center-social">
   <div id="center-s"> 
 <ul class="social-media">
 <li><img src="images/twitter-social.jpg" alt="Gezzamondo on Twitter" title-"Gezzamondo on Twitter"/></li>
 <li><img src="images/behance-social.jpg" alt="Gezzamondo on Behance" title="Gezzamondo on Behance"/></li>
 <li class="last"><img src="images/dribbble-social.jpg" alt="Gezzamondo on Dribbble" title="Gezzamondo on Dribbble"/></li>
 </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```